# send image over sockets in c#

Tags: c#, image, screenshot

I'm trying to create a simple screen broadcast app.
To transfer data I use a socket. I tried to convert the screenshot to a byte array and send it, but the picture just does not come. Any idea would help me.
**The code of the source computer:**

```
Bitmap bmp = TakeScreenshot();                 
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);                                
myNetStream.Write(ms.ToArray(), 0, int.Parse(ms.Length.ToString()));
```

**The code of the target computer:**

```
Image bitmap = Image.FromStream(myNetStream);
```

Thanks!

Comment: `int.Parse(ms.Length.ToString())` why are you doing this? why not just `ms.Length`

Comment: Why not write to myNetStream directly? Skip the MemoryStream.

Comment: Indeed, what @Magnus said